Book series about a girl who has to live with a vampire
The book starts with the protagonist (young girl) climbing a mountain and getting kidnapped by a young male vampire.  She has to live with him as a servant, and at first she's afraid, but later she feels sorry for him.  He's very beautiful but has no emotions because his soul has been stolen by the vampire that bit/created him.  She finds out later that his soul can be regained from a lead vial kept by the vampire that bit him.  She helps him with the aid of a centaur, and the vampire and the girl run away together.  I think there's a sequel as well.
Does anyone know what I'm talking about?  I believe it was published in the 90s or maybe the 2000s, with a dark cover featuring a pale vampire with spread wings that looks like an angel.

You're describing The Darkangel, first book of Meredith Ann Pierce's Darkangel trilogy, published in the 80's.
The girl is Aeriel, and the "centaur" is probably the Starhorse, a lon - a magical entity that was charged with watching over the land the titular darkangel had conquered, killing the horse in the process (it gets better). Or possibly you're thinking of the duarough, a dwarf-like creature who helps Aeriel.
It's his heart, not his soul, that gets coated in lead as a way for his "mother" the White Witch to control him. He does collect the souls of the women he kidnaps and marries and stores them in vials - when he has 14, his transformation from a boy originally named Irrylath to a vampyre will be complete. Aeriel's original mistress is bride number 13.

Duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/283119/fantasy-novel-with-a-girl-trying-to-save-her-friend-from-becoming-a-harpy
